# Enterprise architect select item dialog

Tags: enterprise-architect

We are using the API

```
elementid=Repository.InvokeConstructPicker("IncludedTypes=Class;StereoType=foo")
```

which opens `select<<Item>>` dialog where user can select only one item at a time.

1. Is there any way to make allow user to select multiple items at a time in the `select<<Item>>` dialog.
2. When the `select<<item>>` dialog is opened by default some of the elements in the dialog should be selected.
3. How to check whether none is selected or cancel button is clicked in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the documentation. Ad 1:

```
val = Repository.InvokeConstructPicker("IncludedTypes=Class;MultiSelect=True;");
```

Ad 2:

> - Selection (optional) - list of comma-separated element GUID's that will be selected by default

```
val = Repository.InvokeConstructPicker("IncludedTypes=Class;Selection={CD97B45C-1A97-4049-BB2E-97EE5951AB20};");
```

I haven't test this, though.

Comment: In the select item dialog how to check<<none>> is selected because on pressing cancel also returns 0 and on press of ok on selecting none also return 0

Comment: That's a question you better ask Sparx.

Comment: is that available or not in EA

Comment: Does my last sentence leave any place of interpretation? How will the weather be next year? Can elephants fly?